# Edited WFS layer was not saved in Database

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I managed to load the WFS and my basemap successfully and managed to get the buttons to show up. The buttons appear correctly like in the working example, for some reason the geometry data isn't being saved. Delete button is working fine (whenever I delete a polygon it is deleted and also in the GeoServer published layer) but editing was not working fine.

i.e. I am able to edit the polygon or line, but it is not saved and whenever I refresh the page it is showing the previous polygon not the edited one.

The bit of my code for posting is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

            var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
            
            featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/Peru',
            featureType: 'Buildings',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
        });


        var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
            //format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({ extractGeometryName: true }),
            url: function (extent) {
                return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                    'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Peru:Buildings&' +
                    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
            projection: proj
        });

        window.loadFeatures = function (response) {
            vectorSource.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response));
        };

        var vectorLayerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: sourceWFS
        });

        var interaction;
   
        var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
            condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
        });
        var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#FF2828'
                })
            })
        });
        var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
            source: vectorLayerWFS.getSource()
        });

        var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        var proj = 'EPSG:4326';
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, vectorLayerWFS],
            target: document.getElementById('map'),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([74.2543165420606, 22.844272350403696], 'EPSG:4326', proj),
                maxZoom: 19,
                zoom: 14,
                projection: proj
            })
        });

        //wfs-t
        var dirty = {};
        var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
            var node;

            function removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, valueToRemove) {
                var propNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("Property");
                for (var i = 0; i < propNodes.length; i++) {
                    var propNode = propNodes[i];
                    var propNameNode = propNode.firstElementChild;
                    var propNameNodeValue = propNameNode.firstChild;
                    if (propNameNodeValue.nodeValue === valueToRemove) {
                        propNode.parentNode.removeChild(propNode);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            switch (mode) {
            
                case 'update':
                    // Update Parameter for new GEOMETRY NODE
                    f.set('geometry', f.getGeometry());
                    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
                    // Remove lower case geometry node which will cause update to fail
                    removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, "geometry");

                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
                    break;
            }
            var xs = new XMLSerializer();
            var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);

            console.log(payload);

            $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Peru/wfs',
                {
                    service: 'WFS',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: 'text/xml',
                    data: payload,
                    error: function (e) {
                        var errorMsg = e ? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
                        alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer. \n\n'
                            + errorMsg);
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data));
                    sourceWFS.clear();

                });
        };

        $('button').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
            $(this).addClass('btn-active');
            map.removeInteraction(interaction);
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear();
            map.removeInteraction(interactionSelect);

            switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
                case 'btnEdit':
                    map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);
                    interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                        features: interactionSelect.getFeatures()
                    });
                    map.addInteraction(interaction);
                    map.addInteraction(interactionSnap);
                    dirty = {};
                    interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                        e.element.on('change', function (e) {
                            dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                        });
                    });
                    interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('remove', function (e) {
                        var f = e.element;
                        if (dirty[f.getId()]) {
                            delete dirty[f.getId()];
                            var featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                            delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                            var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                            clone.setId(f.getId());
                            transactWFS('update', clone);
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                case 'btnDelete':
                    interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
                    interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                        transactWFS('delete', e.target.item(0));
                        interactionSelectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                        interaction.getFeatures().clear();
                    });
                    map.addInteraction(interaction);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The XML request that I have sent:

```
<Transaction
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Update typeName="feature:Buildings"
        xmlns:feature="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/Peru">
        <Property>
            <Name>OBJECTID</Name>
            <Value>21348</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>BUILDINGNA</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>BUILDINGAD</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>SHAPE_Leng</Name>
            <Value>70.10207871120306</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>SHAPE_Area</Name>
            <Value>272.00550843505323</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>height</Name>
            <Value>7000</Value>
        </Property>
        <Filter
            xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <FeatureId fid="Buildings.21342"/>
        </Filter>
    </Update>
</Transaction>
```

The Response that I have got is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:TransactionResponse
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:TransactionSummary>
        <wfs:totalInserted>0</wfs:totalInserted>
        <wfs:totalUpdated>1</wfs:totalUpdated>
        <wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted>
    </wfs:TransactionSummary>
    <wfs:TransactionResults/>
    <wfs:InsertResults>
        <wfs:Feature>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="none"/>
        </wfs:Feature>
    </wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

The Geoserver log:

```
2021-10-07 14:13:06,097 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-07 14:13:06,103 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.2591192884007 : 74.26333035655408, 22.81705553923211 : 22.82107885275445] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-07 14:13:06,108 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-10-07 14:13:09,296 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-07 14:13:09,299 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.22062799683354 : 74.28800508728764, 22.812085842224985 : 22.876458858582406] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-07 14:13:09,302 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-10-07 14:13:11,114 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-07 14:13:11,124 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.22772333549383 : 74.29510042594794, 22.797780728352006 : 22.862153744709428] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-07 14:13:11,126 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-10-07 14:13:50,577 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-07 14:13:50,602 INFO [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {Peru}Buildings TransactionEventType[PreUpdate]
2021-10-07 14:13:50,649 INFO [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {Peru}Buildings TransactionEventType[PostUpdate]
2021-10-07 14:13:50,682 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished TRUNCATE task after 0.0 seconds
2021-10-07 14:13:50,688 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished TRUNCATE task after 0.001 seconds
2021-10-07 14:13:50,687 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished TRUNCATE task after 0.005 seconds
2021-10-07 14:13:50,687 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:update=net.opengis.wfs.impl.UpdateElementTypeImpl@19a11626 (filter: [ Buildings.21342 ], handle: null, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null, typeName: {Peru}Buildings)
    update[0]:
        property[0]:
            name = OBJECTID
            value = 21348property[0]:
            name = BUILDINGNAproperty[0]:
            name = BUILDINGADproperty[0]:
            name = SHAPE_Leng
            value = 70.10207871120306property[0]:
            name = SHAPE_Area
            value = 272.00550843505323property[0]:
            name = height
            value = 7000
        filter = [ Buildings.21342 ]
        inputFormat = x-application/gml:3
        typeName = {Peru}Buildings
    releaseAction = ALL
2021-10-07 14:13:50,682 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished TRUNCATE task after 0.0 seconds
2021-10-07 14:13:51,204 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-07 14:13:51,226 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.26142619629152 : 74.26353173036821, 22.81927679566077 : 22.82128845242194] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-07 14:13:51,236 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: We need to see **exactly** what is being sent to GeoServer and what is being returned by GeoServer - If there is an error in the response and it is not obvious what the problem is then you will need to turn logging up to DEVELOPER and repeat the request and add the **relevant** part of the log to your question using the [edit] link

Comment: as far as GeoServer is concerned it has updated your feature so all is well? maybe you forgot to send the modified feature? We need to see exactly what is being sent to GeoServer

Comment: Once I modify the feature it was not updated instead it was deleted. I don't know why this happened.

Comment: please do not use screen shots to show text - it is very hard/impossible for some people to read them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, could you please helpo me.

Comment: Still can't help with out the detailed log file entries for this transaction - Everything looks fine to GeoServer

Comment: I have added the log and I'm getting this<ows:ExceptionText>No such property: geometry</ows:ExceptionText>

Comment: that is the *response* not the *log* - the log will be in `$GEOSERVER_HOME/logs/geoserver.log`

Comment: I had resolved the error [No such property: geometry] but the updated feature layer was not updated on map as well as in database. I have added Geoserver log also.

Answer (score 0):

Observed that XML transaction generated by your code does not contain geometry property.

Add following line

```js
// Add following line 

clone.setGeometryName('geom');

//just before 

transactWFS('update', clone);
```